# Angular, Ionic: RxJs Pipe with MAP does not return value in windows, but works in mac when used with httpclient

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am using RxJs Pipe with Map to make a network call in my Angular/Ionic project, I get a successful response in the network log but the MAP function does not return any value

**Observations**

However, the same function works fine in Mac, but in windows, it does get called once, but subsequent calls will return nothing,
In the below snippet, the control never enters map value even when the response is success

**Code**

```js
.get(`${API_HOST}/${API_URL}/${userId}`,options)
.pipe(map((profile) => {
          return profile;
        })
```

**Question:**

1) Is this a known BUG?

2) Is there a workaround or foolproof method to get the response data without using MAP function?

Comment: Looks strange to me, because you don't subscribe the observable.

Comment: @DaniR can u elaborate

Answer (score 0):

The `map`-operator also returns an Observable (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) so you have to subscribe on it.
You can try:

```
.get(`${API_HOST}/${API_URL}/${userId}`,options)
    .pipe(map(profile => profile))
    .subscribe(profile => console.log(profile));
```

Comment: doesnt work either, im returning a observable, hence my earlier statement was currect

Comment: Yeah you return an observable. That‘s why you have to subscribe on it (Documentation above). If you do, then next time provide more code. I don‘t think it‘s a windows problem, because the server is a 3rd-party-tool like http-server. But i am the wrong one for this question.

Comment: Yea I looked at it, also I tried your approach, it never goes to subscribe after 1 or 2 times, so the thing is, the function works, but not all the time, but working seamlessly in mac, like to belive its not windows issue, but can't understand this behavior

Comment: That sounds like a server problem. But i‘m really the wrong one to answer this question.